# Bootstrap drop down not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to do like this

[image]

and so I tried this [way](http://bootply.com/112642)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="col-md-2 ">
<button class="icon-box-add dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">  Stock
 <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>


</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Orders</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Content</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Setting</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Marketting</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Customers</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But the output is not as per my requirement(as per the image shown). Please tell me how to do

**NOTE** Please ignore the icons,I can not attach images in bootply.

Comment: Please, in bootply, save your project, because your link is a new bootply...

Comment: Your bootply is a new empty project; please share your demo

Comment: @Jahnux73 sorry,my foolishness.I have updated it.Please check

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Sorry for that.Now I have updated.Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it can help you :

**bootply :** http://bootply.com/112644

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="btn-group col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
  <a class="icon-box-add dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">  Stock
   <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>        
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>


  </div>
<div class="col-md-2">Orders</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Content</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Setting</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Marketting</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Customers</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

http://bootply.com/112648
Change `col-md-2` to just `pull-left`

http://bootply.com/112649
Add margin-right

**Update 2 :**
Comment : In the image the divs are side by side

In adding a backgound (as your image), you can see that they are side by side...
http://bootply.com/112650

Comment: In the image the divs are side by side as you can see but the bootply there are spaces(example spaces between stock and order).How can it removed

Comment: There are a lot a answer so: check my updates please, oups a find something, please wait...

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.Well see the code I have posted is having only one drop down(stocks) but I want all the fields dropdown(as given  in the image(stocks,orders,settings) all are dropdown.So if I make all dropdown then out of the 4 links you have suggested which one should I use

Comment: No friend.well i will not disturb you any more.Thanks again for answering